# Can I use Firebug to display objects of an app?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug

I am not completely familiar with JavaScript. In order to understand some pieces of code in (Firefox) apps, I would like to know if there is a way to display the content of some objects "in vivo", i.e. in an interactive fashion, instead of writing `console.log()` in the app.js and restarting the browser every time.

Comment: You mean like console.log() or inspect element?

Comment: yes, I would like to avoid to place console.log in the app.js, and directly view the objects within firebug, if it is possible

Comment: You could put a watch on objects in debug mode [docs](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/readability/source-maps?hl=en)

Comment: With this kind of tool, can one access to the objects/variables of apps installed in firefox/myProfile/extensions ?. For the moment I see only the different objects/variables available which are coming with the current html page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display the objects of an app within the [*DOM* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/DOM_Panel) or while debugging within the [*Watch* side panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Watch_Side_Panel) of the [*Script* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Panel). Just expand the tree of objects.

*Note that [Firebug stops working once multi-process Firefox](https://blog.getfirebug.com/2016/06/07/unifying-firebug-firefox-devtools/) is enabled, so you're better off by switching to the [Firefox DevTools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) (and/or other browser's developer tools), which offer similar functionality.*